# Running C program in Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

I have a set of C code files named as: hmc.c hopping.c phi4.c and I have an 'infile' which contains value of parameters and a 'Makefile'. How do I run these set of files in Ubuntu?
Previously in Windows I used gcc compiler with command 'gcc hmc.c hopping.c phi4.c' and then press Enter and then 'a infile' and that did the expected job but on Ubunut it isn't working..

Comment: "it isn't working" is a useless description. Explain *how exactly* it isn't working.

Comment: If you have a Makefile, use it. There should be also some source for these and reason the files exist and someone who created them, who knows better than us what should be done

Comment: the content of the makefile, the 'infile' and the traceback would be useful. have you tried the `make` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the makefile should compile and give you an executable. You can do so by entering `make` in the command line. Make sure you have it installed first.